# How do i scrape all content if it has various tags within it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider that i'd like to scrape an article i'm interested in, then store the title and the content in a dictionary. However, when i scrape the body it returns the html code, of which i want to convert to text (including all the h1 and href within the article), but when i use .getall() it returns an empty list. How do i make this all into text and still keep all of the content within the article.

in the scrapy shell i have tried which returned a large list containing all of the html code.

```
    response.css("div.rich-text-content").getall()
```

below is the initial spider that i have created in order to do this task...

```
  class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "article"

        def start_requests(self):
            urls = [
                "https://www.codehousegroup.com/insight-and-inspiration/tech-stream/what-is-machine-learning"
            ]
            for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

        def parse(self, response):
              for quote in response.css("div.article-page"):
                yield {
                    'heading': quote.css("h1::text").get(),
                    'text': quote.css("p.rectangle-decoration::text").get(),
                    'body': quote.css("div.rich-text-content rich-text-content::text").getall(),
                }
```

The expected results is a string with the everything currently in the body item of my dictionary just without the tags.

Comment: There is nice and easy to use `html2text` module

Comment: Also https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, you need to select all inside elements in the div tag and return their text.

You can use * in css which will select all inside elements:

'body': quote.css("div.rich-text-content *::text").getall()

Comment: hmm this could be one way, though it returns a very messy list. i guess i could split by the '\n' and join it all together... if there is a more efficient way let me know!

Comment: There is no other way than collect all the texts in a list. You can then process the list in Items.py using input/output processors.

If you get unnecessary items you can edit the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xpath` instead css.

Example:

```
for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="article-page"]'):
    text = quote.xpath("/h1/text()").get()
    ...
```

Comment: i am reasonably new to scrapy, but from what i have read (correct me if i am wrong please) there is not much difference between using css and xpath unless you are querying by path, of which the documentation suggest it is better to use css. Regardless, this still leads to the same problem of just getting the html and not the text.

Comment: Xpath is a standard to lookup information in XML (or HTML) files. 
I let you here a tutorial https://docs.scrapy.org/en/xpath-tutorial/topics/xpath-tutorial.html